# How do I set a bounty on my Java question?

Tags: support, specific-question, bounties

My question, [Problem in HtmlUnit API for Java (Headless Browser)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131049/problem-in-htmlunit-api-for-java-headless-browser) wallows in the depths of having no answers which I find to solve my dilemma.

How do I go about setting a bounty on this question?

Is it even possible for me to do so? If so, how?

Comment: I don't think half an hour counts as wallowing in the depths; it's barely paddling and splashing on the beach. 

Patience, young padowan.

Comment: @Unsliced: To be fair, that phrase comes from random's edit, not from the OP.

Comment: @balpha yeah, maybe - but he had only waited half an hour before asking the question, so the phrasing wasn't his, but the impatience certainly was! If the cap fits ...

Comment: @Unsliced: Impatience conceded; however, the original question sounds more like a "need introduction to the bounty system" than a "the question has been sitting there for more than 5 minutes, and still no answer!" I think the OP assumed that you put a bounty on a question right away to express how important the Q is to you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait two days and have enough reputation before you can start a bounty.

Comment: Where is it written, by the way, these 2 days? Maybe this should be more clear in the FAQ.

Comment: @Gnoupi - from the FAQ - "If, after 2 days, you still don't have an answer you like, you can  offer a bounty."

Comment: @ChrisF - Of course, if I check only the Meta FAQ...

Answer (score 0):

From the [Stackoverflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty):

> **What if I don't get a good answer?**
>
> In order to get good answers, you have to put some effort into the question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.
>
> If, after 2 days, you still don't have an answer you like, you can offer a bounty. Slice off a bit of your own hard-earned reputation -- anywhere from 50 to 500 -- and attach it to the question as a bounty. We'll even throw in 50 reputation to sweeten the deal. The bountied question will appear with a special icon in all question lists, and it will also be visible on the home page Featured tab.